# Using W3 Total Cache, I set expire headers to media, css and js files,but it seems doesn't work

Tags: plugins

I used W3 total cache to improve the site performance. The problem is I've set expire headers to my media,css and js files, but when I run test in page insight and gtmetrix,the report indicate I did't set expire header to the files. I've checked the .htaccess file, there are rules in it. What do you guys think the problem? Thanks!

Comment: give us a link so we can inspect

Comment: http://doshooting.ulandtech.com/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first port of call would be to make sure that you have all the appropriate modules enabled for your server. For example, on a LAMP stack:

In your apache's http.conf the following lines would need to be uncommented

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
```

You would need to restart your apache server for this to take effect